# The line break is not working in Laravel blade.php

Tags: php, line-breaks, laravel-blade

```
@foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
  @php
    $message .= $error . '<br/>';
  @endphp
@endforeach
```

I use `$message` on blade: 
`<section class="content">
  @include('includes.partials.messages')
    @yield('content')
</section>`

I have tried `<br>`, `<br/>`,`\n` etc, not work.
waiting for help

Comment: Welcome. How do you know it doesn't work, you don't output `$message` anywhere

Comment: Thank you @kerbholz it output as "text text text text <br/> text text text text" on screen, it is an error alert.
btw, my English is not good enough.

Comment: Could you please edit your question and add the part where/how you output `$message`? (I assume it's `{{ $message }}`, if that's how you output it try `{!! $message !!}` instead, so HTML gets interpreted as HTML)

Comment: Thanks for your patience, @kerbholz.
I have edited it.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, but it still doesn't show how you output `$message` anywhere. As of now, you're only assigning `$message`.

Answer (score 2):

Blade, by default, will call the [`e` helper function](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/helpers#method-e), which calls the [`htmlspecialchars`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php), when you use the double curly braces.

That means that this:

```
{{ 'test test <br /> test test' }}
```

Would render as:

```
<?php echo e('test test <br /> test test'); ?>
```

And then subsequently display as:

```
test test &lt;br /&gt; test test
```

---

If you do not want your strings escaping - in case they display HTML - then use the following:

```
{!! $message !!}
```

Which will not escape your strings and it will display as you expected.

**Note**: Please note, however, that there are security risks here as someone can use [XSS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) if you are not careful.

Comment: Thank you @JustCarty, I tried it earlier today, but it doesn't work.
I don‘t know why, anyway thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I see that you are using the errors in Laravel Blade

Maybe you can use this example

```
<ul>
    @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
        <li>{{ $error }}</li>
    @endforeach
</ul>
```

That will show each error in the bag. You can also change the `li` tags to something you like

Source: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/validation

Comment: Hello Koen Please add <ul> tag you miss in for each loop.

Comment: Thanks you both, just did

Comment: Met another problem with my computer, once my computer is fixed I will continue to try, thanks again @KoenHollander

Comment: It works, @KoenHollander, thank you Koen.
but it accompanied another problem, the error msg didn't disappeared on the top of the page after I re-inputted it with correct format. How to solve this problem?

Comment: Can you use `var_dump` on `$errors` instead of the foreach? Let's see what that is doing :P

Comment: Sorry it doesn't work, @KoenHollander.
but thank you a lot, and I followed you on GitHub and Facebook.